# Can TextMate be changed to "shift text to right" by highlighting text and pressing Tab?

Tags: textmate

Can TextMate be changed to "shift text to right" by highlighting text and pressing Tab?

Right now it actually replace the whole selected text with a tab character but I almost never want to do something like that.  I think some other editors like Notepad++ will indent to the next level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cmd + ]` will shift text to the right.

If you really want to use Tab for that, then make a new command in the bundle editor and paste this in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$: << ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib'
require 'escape'
def esc(str)
  e_sn(str).gsub(/\}/, '\\}') # escaping inside a placeholder
end

s = STDIN.read
if s.empty? then
  print "\t"
else
  print "\t#{e_sn s}"
end
```

Then set the key equivalent to Tab.

Comment: While this does work, I've just realised that it pretty much disables tab triggers, which are one of the main reasons I use TextMate, so be warned!

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Tab works too.

Lorem ipsrum at least 30 chars..